# Searching for an answer

Tags: python

I am currently learning Class Keyword and Attributes - I am using IDE pycharm and keep getting this error. Am I missing something?

[image: my code]

Comment: `__init__` has two underscores on either side.

Comment: By the way, your question is likely to get downvoted and/or closed, because it looks like you haven't read [ask]. You should write an informative title which describes your problem, and include your code and the error message directly, not as an image (or a link to an image).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I'm new here so now I know for next time

Comment: No worries. By the way, don't take downvotes personally - they are used by the community to keep it so that search results are likely to return questions that are useful to other people - it doesn't mean you aren't welcome here. But I do recommend reading through the help pages and taking a look at some upvoted questions and answers to see what the norms are here; you'll find it easier to participate and get more out of it then.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the "mybreed" variable anywhere. Try the below:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, breed):
        self.breed = breed

my_dog = Dog('Lab')
```

Answer (score 0):

you must definite the variable

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, breed):
        self.mybreed = breed

my_dog = Dog(breed='Lab')
```

that is perfect.

(Next time, put the code up in text.)

thank you